# My Sql Database Table Will Not Show Data That I Wish To Insert Into It With VB 2008 Express

Tags: vb.net

I'm quite new into the programming game, I've been working on this program for a few weeks now, and its coming along, but the method I searched for entering new rows of data into my table doesn't seem to update my tables after I try entering data. I have a feeling it may be something very simple that i am over looking.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks

```
Private Sub Button4_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
   Handles Button4.Click

    Dim conn As New SqlConnection("my datasource")
    Dim comm As New SqlCommand()

    comm.Connection = conn

    comm.CommandText() = "INSERT INTO inventoryTable(item, itemDescription, quantity, purchasePrice, markUp, sellingPrice, paymentMethod, paymentAmount) VALUES (@ParameterItem,@ParameterItemD,@ParameterQuan,@ParameterPurch,@ParameterMark,@ParameterSell,@ParameterPm,@ParameterPa)"

    comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ParameterItem", TextBox1.Text)
    comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ParameterItemD", TextBox8.Text)
    comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ParameterQuan", TextBox2.Text)
    comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ParameterPurch", TextBox3.Text)
    comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ParameterMark", TextBox4.Text)
    comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ParameterSell", TextBox5.Text)
    comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ParameterPm", ComboBox2.Text)
    comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ParameterPa", TextBox6.Text)

    Try

        conn.Open()
        comm.ExecuteNonQuery()
        conn.Close()

    Catch ex As Exception

        MsgBox(ex.Message)

    End Try

    'TextBox7.Text = TextBox1.Text + ", " + TextBox8.Text + ", " + TextBox2.Text + ", " + TextBox3.Text + ", " + TextBox4.Text + ", " + TextBox5.Text + ", " + ComboBox2.Text + ", " + TextBox6.Text

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If that is your verbatim code, then the problem is in the connection string.  You'd need to replace "my datasource" with an actual connection string.  Check out this website for help on creating a connection string:

http://www.connectionstrings.com/

Disregard this as silliness if you simply removed the connection string before posting on here.

Comment: haha..sorry about that, i should have clarified, yea, i removed the data source.  the problem is that my program when i run it runs through everything problem free, but when i pull up the data in the table, the new entry is no where to be seen

Comment: Gotcha, just making sure =).  Did you check to see what the call to "comm.ExecuteNonQuery()" returns?  It should give you back an integer telling you how many records were affected.

Comment: how would i be able to do that? i cant just send it to a message box can i?

Comment: Dim temp As String = comm.ExecuteNonQuery()
            MsgBox(temp)

Comment: i tried that ^, and the message box came back with the response "1", but its still not in the database table

Comment: How are you checking the data table, is that in your program too?  Did you try looking directly in the database (with SQL Server Management Studio or Access, or whatever database you're using)?  Because that's strange!

Comment: The code that's in the beginning is all that I have.  I have looked for more examples online, and ive actually found so many that look like what i have already.  My problem is that for some reason my database does not show any updates to them.....

Comment: it is sql...here was the problem, i found it, i was saving it into another database than the one i was looking for...the data base i was looking into was db.mdf ...the database it saved data in was db.mdf1 ...is that normal?

Comment: I've never heard of that, but [this](http://forums.asp.net/t/1025932.aspx/1) fellow had a similar issue and said it was a permissions problem (although he didn't go into any details =/).  At least your code was good, good work!